# What's the easiest way to remove linebreaks from XML data

Tags: xml, powershell

I have some XML source files that have been hard-wrapped so linebreaks have been added to the text data where lines are long.  They're removed in the output.  I'd like them to line up nicely side-by-side so our QA people have an easier time eyeballing them.  It's a docBook project, if anyone's interested.

I've been mucking around with powershell but I was wondering if there's some off-the-shelf software that will do it.  The pretty-printing in Notepad++ won't work inside the tags.

Answer (score 0):

To format nicely just do,

```
$xml = [xml] (gc c:\path\to\file.xml)
$xml.Save([Console]::Out)
```

Originally from the [Windows PowerShell Cookbook for Windows, Exchange 2007, and MOM V3](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528492.do).